# SQL Server: table datatypes to smallest possible space to overcome limit of maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes?

Tags: sql-server, csv, sqldatatypes

I am getting a similar error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219607/sql-server-row-size-limit-and-table-design)

> Creating or altering table 'MediaLibrary' failed because the minimum
>   row size would be 14273, including 9 bytes of internal overhead. This
>   exceeds the maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes.

after importing a CSV with SQL Server Management Studio. Number columns are interpreted as strings so, instead of efficient (n)archer(x) datatype, the datatype may be nchar(1000) taking a lot of unnecessary space.

How can I see the datatypes of the table imported to SQL Server and update them to take the smallest amount of space?

Comment: `"the datatypes of the table imported to SQL Server"`. What table? I think you say `CSV`

Comment: @Sami In MMSM, right click on the DB such that `Tasks > Import Data > Flat file` so you can import CSV file into a table in MMSM but no ado about the datatypes of the table.

Comment: You mean `DT_STR`?

Comment: @hhh, you can specify the proper data types and lengths in the SSMS SSIS import wizard. Click on "Advanced" and specify for each column.

Comment: @Dan You are right and this probably solves the issue, could you elaborate in an answer about how you would use the wizard? I have ID field and month field and then all other field are floats or numeric (not sure about difference). For optimal space allocation, which data types are most optimal and when?

Answer (score 0):

Create table in sql database and define columns with proper data types than import CSV into table
if you have only string columns in table and each column can have 1000 chars I think that you need to split table and join in view